# Xamarin Live Reload Preview doesen't connect with android emulator

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

i started recently working on a app for mobile devices with xamarin forms. To work on the GUI fluently i tried this:

[Live Reload Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinLiveReload#overview)

It worked with the Visual Studio Android Emulator. But i want to work with google's emulator becaus of the more recent updates. I get in VS the message, that LiveReload is enabled but not listening. So i tried a view things with the "Hostname" and "Port" field within the settings of live reload in VS. If i use the command "adb devices" i can see the emulator and it's port (5554 in my case).

Should Hostname stay at localhost? Or did i miss something? The project worked fine with VS Android Emulator and the Live Reload extension. So i can at least exclude a mistake in my code.

Would be great if there's someone who could help :)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/player?tabs=windows), you can use `Xamarin Live Player app`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The Xamarin Live Player App worked fine (didn't mention i tested it before, sry, my bad). But i would like to use the android emulator. If there is no other way right now, i'll have to stay with the Live Player i guess...